# relations between properties of stochastic processess

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stationary-processes

If we have an **integer valued stochastic process**, are these implications correct?

1. independent increments $\rightarrow$ Markov property
2. Markov property $\nrightarrow$ independent increments
3. stationary increments $\rightarrow$ time homogenity
4. time homogenity $\nrightarrow$ stationary increments
5. stationary increments $\rightarrow$ independent increments $\rightarrow$ Markov Property
6. independent increments $\nrightarrow$ stationary increments

PS: I got number 2 answered by an example in another thread, but I would like to know all on this list aswell, because it is confusing for me. You don't need to make me examples if this is too much work for you, please then just tell me if the impliations hold or not.

I made a picture to describe it, is it correct?

[image: pic]

Comment: Much more interesting would be you telling us why you think these implications hold. For example, why do you think that stationary increments → independent increments?

Comment: Hello. I am very unsure but on that case I thought like this: Lets say we want to calculate P([x(t+s)-x(t)=j]|[x(t)-x(0)=i]). Since stationary increments means that it only depends on the length of the interval this is P([x(t+s)-x(t)=j])=P([x(s)-x(0)=j]),so the information about what happened before doesn't mean anything, hence we also have independent increments. But I am very unsure of this.

Comment: "Stationary increments" does not mean that, please check the definitions.

Comment: @Did The only definition of stationary increments in my book was this one: http://s2.postimg.org/g5rjhnpo9/image.png But I see now that it is for a counting process, and it might not be enough for a general integer valued process. I guess that general stationary increments means that it only depends on the time interval, but also the state it is in in the start of the increment.

Comment: But where you are at the start of the increment, may depend on an earlier increment. So the distribution may still depend on what happened earlier. I updated the picture, is one of the two pictures in the updated version correct?: http://s30.postimg.org/uyqucthox/updated.png

Comment: Another one: why "stationary increments → time homogenity"?

Comment: @Did Again I am really unsure about this, but I thought like this: To show time-homogenity we must show that P(x(t+s)=j|x(t)=i)=P(x(s)=j|x(0)=i). Så I start with LHS: P(x(t+s)=j|x(t)=i)=P(x(t+s)-x(t)=j-i|x(t)=i). By stationary increments this gives: P(x(s)-x(0)=j-i|x(0)=i)=P(x(s)=j|x(0)=i)

Comment: "Time homogeneity" does not mean that, please check the definitions (bis).

Comment: @Did Sorry but I am very confused. If I instead of integer valued processes only looked at counting processess, would then what I wrote in comment #2 about statioanry-> independent make sense? And would then what I wrote in comment #7 be correct? The definition of time homogeneous in my book is this:http://s28.postimg.org/yabv7mqy5/timeh.png However I see that it is defined under Markov chains. Will any of the pictures be correct if we only consider counting processess? I should maybe have started with this, because my book only talks about

Comment: increments in counting processess not general integer processess.